# How to load balance Stateful application running on 2 pods

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, metallb

I want to load-balance 2 stateful applications running on 2 pods. This application cannot have 2 replicas as it is stateful.

I tried giving the same service names to both the pods but it looks like Kubernetes get confused and nothing is served.

I am using on-premies Kubernetes cluster with metallb as a load-balancer.

Currently, these pods are exposed over public IP with service TYPE as a load-balancer and added A record to both the pods. But it cannot do a health check with DNS.

I only think of having Nginx pod and do mod-proxy to it. Is there any better solution other than this?

Answer (score 1):

The selector on a service can be anything, and can match pods from multiple statefulsets (or deployments). So make a label on your pods and use that in the selector of a new service to target both.

Comment: Will the below selector  in service does loadbalance if type is loadbalancer ?
```selector:
    app: waxapi
    app: waxapi2```

Comment: `selector:
        app: waxapi
        app: waxapi2`